# Converting an AM/PM time to 24 hours format using PHP or MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a string of time such as: 6:00 AM, 7:30 PM, etc. It can easily be changed to 6:00:00 AM, 7:30:00 PM, etc as well.

I'm looking for a way to quickly convert this time into a 24 hour format, e.g 7:30 PM = 19:30:00.

Is there any PHP or MySQL function which has this capability, or do I have to devise my own?

Comment: @zerkms How long I've been on this site or how good or bad of a programmer I am are irrelavent. This site is about asking and answering programming questions, that's it.

Comment: that's about teaching people to be better specialists (at least I hope so). Not for the people who are too lazy to read documentation and write 3 lines function.

Comment: @zerkms No, its just about answering the questions which are asked, not trying to get involved with someone in a personal way.

Comment: Just confess that you're using stackoverflow because you're too lazy to do your work yourself? ;-)

Comment: @zerkms Its none of your business what I use stackoverflow for mate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
STR_TO_DATE( `column_here`, '%l:%i %p' )
```

Read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

## EDIT

Edited `'%l:%M %p'` to `'%l:%i %p'`

Comment: Nope, I tried `SELECT STR_TO_DATE( '10:00:00 PM', '%l:%M %p' )` and got NULL as the return value. I've tried DATE_FORMAT as well and got the same thing. It seems that both functions can only format things which are already in mysql DATETIME format

Comment: @ClickUpvote That's because the format string, `%l:%M $p` in my case, refers to the formatting of the input. For `'10:00:00 PM'`; You'll need `%l:%M:%S %p`

Comment: `SELECT STR_TO_DATE(  '10:00:00 PM',  '%l:%M:%S %p' )` still gives null

Comment: Your edit fixed it. `SELECT STR_TO_DATE(  '10:00:00 PM',  '%l:%i:%S %p' )` gives 22:00:00 as expected

Comment: its working SELECT STR_TO_DATE( '10:00:00 PM', '%l:%i:%S %p' ) so the full date format is SELECT STR_TO_DATE('5/16/2011 04:14:00 AM', '%c/%e/%Y %l:%i:%S %p')

Answer (score 1):

Try [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php), which retrieves the Unix timestamp for any english date/time format. If it doesn't work out of the box, maybe add an arbitrary day in front of the time string you pass along. Then you can use [strftime](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.strftime.php) to convert the timestamp into a 24h format.

Also I've heard of a `DateTime` object, which may be able to handle both conversions as well.

Comment: I don't have a unix timestamp, only a string in the format HH:MM AM/PM. I guesss I'll have to write my own function to convert it to 24h.

Comment: As I said. strtotime RETRIEVES the timestamp from any english format. So you use `strtotime("11:00:00 pm")` (maybe add an arbitrary date in front) and get a timestamp, which you than can convert with `strftime` into a 24h format.

Answer (score 0):

**Do Like That**

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('08:35 PM', '%l:%i %p');
```

**ANS: '20:35:00'**

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query,

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE( '2019-06-19 10:00 pm', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p' );
```

We have to use the date for getting the proper time in 24 hours. You can add any static date before the time, above solution worked for me :)