# query to change mysql 12 hour time to 24 hour time

Tags: mysql

i have in a table column time field stored in this format  "8:54:11 PM" which is in 12 hour  time format i will like to make it look like this
"20:54:11" which is a 24 hour format.

Comment: Can you give better example data place it on sql-fiddle.com or db-fiddle.com.

Comment: Store data using the correct data type for that data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting an AM/PM time to 24 hours format using PHP or MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397591/converting-an-am-pm-time-to-24-hours-format-using-php-or-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MySQL `TIME` type does not store a time in any specific format. It depends on the query that reads the time to decide how to show it.

For instance, the following query selects a field of type `TIME` and returns it in 24-hour format.

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(mytime, '%T');
```

Comment: i tried that  SELECT DATE_FORMAT('3:02:28 PM', '%T'); but the result is 00:00:00

Comment: Sorry, I should have written `TIME_FORMAT`. That should work.

Comment: what is get now is the PM is just removed  03:02:28

Comment: I tried those fix i was getting a null result but here is how i got by   select Addtime('10:02:00 PM', '12:00:00'); and i got 22:02:00

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
STR_TO_DATE(dateColumn, '%l:%i:%s %p' )
```

the meaning of the formats you can look here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/340e01/494

Answer (score 1):

This question has already being answered here:

[Converting an AM/PM time to 24 hours format using PHP or MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397591/converting-an-am-pm-time-to-24-hours-format-using-php-or-mysql)

As I can't comment yet neither set is as duplicated I'm posting it as an answer.